# Why there is de-excitation time for an atom after it gets excited by beta particles moving faster than light

Tags: cherenkov-radiation

I have not found the time for de-excitation of an electron when they are excited by the beta particles moving faster than the speed of light in the medium (water, glass etc)  or the emission of cherenkov radiation is instantaneous?

Answer (score 1):

[Cerenkov radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation#Basic) does not happen because of excitation and de-excitation of atoms, it happens in the fringe fields that exist in a medium. The same fields that build up chemical bonds, are responsible for the difference of the [velocity of light in a medium.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity) See below explanation with polarization in a dielectric medium

> While the speed of light in a vacuum is a universal constant (c = 299,792,458 m/s), the speed in a material may be significantly less, as it is perceived to be slowed by the medium. For example, in water it is only 0.75c. Matter can accelerate beyond this speed (although still less than c, the speed of light in vacuum) during nuclear reactions and in particle accelerators. Cherenkov radiation results when a charged particle, most commonly an electron, travels through a dielectric (can be polarized electrically) medium with a speed greater than light's speed in that medium

[This link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/cherenkov-radiation) has a lot of references:

> Cherenkov photon emission is the result of local polarization along the path of travel of the charged particle with the emission of electromagnetic radiation when the polarized molecules return to their original states (see Gruhn and Ogle, 1980). This has been described by Marshall (1952) as the electromagnetic “shock” wave that is analogous to the acoustical shock wave or sonic boom created by supersonic aircraft. The Cherenkov effect is depicted clearly by Burden and Hieftje (1998), as illustrated in Fig. 9.1, where the charged particle (e.g., electron or β particle) distorts the electron clouds of atoms in close proximity to the high-speed particle traversing a transparent medium.

You ask:

> or the emission of cherenkov radiation is instantaneous?

Of course not, every electromagnetic interaction is bounded by the speed of light

Comment: Nice answer. Can you please elaborate on this: "fringe fields that exist in a medium.". Cherenkov radiation should be photons, but where does that energy of the photons come from? Does it come from the EM field inside the medium or does it come from the atoms of the medium? Or is it the electron's kinetic energy that it is losing (slowing down)?

Comment: @ÁrpádSzendrei  it is the electrons that lose energy, as in the sonic boom it is the aeroplane that burns extra fuel. I added a link.